# How to fill google maps height in android api v2?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

How to fill Google Maps height....

[image]

In the Red box are the empty spaces. How to avoid that....

**XML Layout File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: show your map fragment layout xml file...

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the Map inside of a `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```